# aws lambda rds proxy network error postgresql serverless v2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I am using a lambda function to query data in an RDS serverless v2 cluster instance.
Everything is in a VPC. The lambda sits in e1a, e1b, e1c, and the rds instance sits in e1a.

I'm using Python 3.9 with SQLAlchemy, and PG8000 for the driver.

I can connect to the cluster writer endpoint without issue using the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import insert, func
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

DATABASE_PASSWORD = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname = 'rds-cluster-writer-endpoint', Port = DATABASE_PORT, DBUsername = DATABASE_USERNAME, Region = None)

DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL = URL.create(
    drivername = 'postgresql+pg8000',
    username = DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password = DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    host = 'rds-cluster-writer-endpoint',
    port = DATABASE_PORT,
    database = DATABASE_SCHEMA
)

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL, connect_args={'ssl_context': True})
print(engine.execute("select * from wtf_aws;"))
```

But I would like to use an RDS proxy if possible.

After setting up an RDS proxy, I modified the above host parameters to use the proxy endpoint instead. I enabled IAM auth as well for the proxy.

Side note: I noticed some weird behavior where if you set IAM auth to enabled for the RDS proxy, the connection seems to fail if you don't 1) have a secret 2) containing a `username` and `password` value. Why is that? Within the secret I set the username to that of the username that I created in the RDS instance and for which I created an IAM policy for that uses a policy similar to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds-db:connect"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "xxx"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I set the password to something random. If we are using IAM auth, why do we also have to have a secret? And why does the secret need to contain a username / password value?

Okay, back to the main question. So once I have these things in place, and the python code pointing to the proxy host instead of the cluster writer host, I get the following error in logs:

```
errorMessage": "(pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError) network error\n[SQL: select pg_catalog.version()]\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue? I would really like to use RDS proxy!

Comment: Think of IAM auth as an extra layer of security on top

Comment: Also - can you check the RDS proxy logs in CloudWatch please and add the logs to your question after retrying the connection? Please also run `aws rds describe-db-proxy-targets --db-proxy-name $DB_PROXY_NAME` replacing `$DB_PROXY_NAME` with your proxy name and add the output to your Q.

Comment: Hi! Have you solved this issue? Could you please share your solution?